# How to return the value of a 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, return-value

I have my array class as shown below, when I run the program, it gives me this error message: `Error: Main method not found in class SArray, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application`
  I have no idea how I should modify my codes to solve this problem, cause it seems that there is no need for me to have a main method.

```
public class SArray {
    public void setS(double[] S) {}

    public SArray(double[] S) {
        super();
    }

    public double[][] getS(){

        double[ ][ ] S =  {{ x,x,x}, { x,x,x},{ x,x,x}}；
        for(int x = 0; x<S.length; x++){ 
            for(int y = 0; y<S[x].length; y++){
                System.out.println(S[x][y]); 
            } 
        }
        return S;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you must write a `main` method to run a standalone Java application. This method is the entry point of the application.

Comment: What do expect to happen when you try to run the program?

Comment: To run your program, you need a `main` method. If this is the only class you have, it must have the main method since... well... a main method must exist in the main class. The only existing class is always the main class

Comment: Why do you think that there is no need for a `main` method? What do you expect your program do to when you run it, as it stands now?

Comment: I just expect to use `S[x][y]` method.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is not related to the return type of `getS` but the project setup expects `SArray` to have an application entry point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `main` method
You can define one in your class, make `new SArray()` and call `getS()` or make new class and place `main` method there

Comment: I tried to put this `SIBORArray a = new SIBORArray;`. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to run, Java needs to know where to start. Else nothing happens

define as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //whatever you want to do
}
```

How else can Java know where to start?

Answer (score 0):

A Java application needs a method named main whose sign is as following:

```
public static main(String[] args)
```

You better check [this page](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/anatomy/main.html) before doing anything with your class.

Answer (score 0):

JVM fisrt search for a entry point (main method) in a program. so you should have at least one main method in your project to run. Otherwise it fails to start

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   //code here
}
```

In your example you have created the `constructor` main can't contain `constructors`. remove the constructor and run **or** create another class and put your main class there and create the instance of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are confusing between the driver class and a class. What I mean is, in your constructor you wrote `super();` which is used when your class is a child class of another, in this case, you should define the parent class in the beginning of the code by using the keyword extends. If you extend another class, you would use the keyword super() inside your constructor in order to get the constructor from your parent class, linking them in a way. For example, you say `public class SArray extends InsertParentsClassName`. Eventually you will still need a driver class to run your code, which is where you would use the other classes you created as objects. The driver class is usually the one that has a main method. So if this is not your driver class, what you can do is create a different class that has a main method and create objects of SArray inside it.

```
public class DriverClass{
     //This is only a rough draft of what it might look like
     SArray array = new SArray();
     public static void main(String [] args){
          //As you can see you can use the functions in SArray class here.
          array.getS();
     }
}
```

On the other hand, if this is your driver class, you are trying to run a code without a main method. This is not possible because Java would not know from where to start. You should add this to your code and your code should go inside the main method. Moreover, you should add the keyword static to all your functions i.e `public static double[][] getS()`

```
public static void main(String[] args){//Insert your code here}
```

This is where your code will be executed.

I suggest you go back to more basic stuff, because this is where Java starts to become more advanced and if you are not good with the basics you will not be able to do well later on.